# Project referencing Portable Class Library gives error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I create a console application in Visual Studio 2015 RC and add Automapper 3.3.1 using nuget to the project.

If I then add the following snippet to my project:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Test()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<B>(new A());
    }
}
```

And then open the same project in Visual Studio Code preview on Windows 10 then I get a red squiggly on the Map function.

The error message says:

> The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.

My project is configured to use .NET 4.52 and there are absolutely no errors or warnings when building the same project using visual studio 2015 RC or using MSBuild from the command line.

Automapper is portable class library and this is what seems to trigger the problem.
Is this a known issue with Visual Studio Code or Omnisharp?
Are there any way to suppress these error messages?

**Update**:
I have now tested with VS Code version 0.3 and it is still not fixed.

To make it even simpler to reproduce I have also verified that the problem also exist for a ClassLibrary project containing only the 3 classes: Class1 as shown and class A and class B, which are just two dummy classes used to have something to map.
It does not matter which version of Visual Studio is used to create the project. The same problem exist if I create the class library project using VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you added the reference in both **dnx451** and **dnxcore50** in *project.json* file.
I think the problem is Automapper did not support .NET Core 5.0, please refer this article for more detail about .NET core 5.0 and .NET framework 4.6.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2014/11/18/what-is-net-core-5-and-asp-net-5-within-net-2015-preview.aspx.

This might be the limitation of multi-environment in **.NET Core 5.0** when using available libraries. You should write by yourself or waiting for other libraries update if you want to use, otherwise, please remove **dnxcore50** in *project.json*.

Happy coding!

Comment: There's no project.json. As I wrote in the question, it is a console application. Not using asp.net 5. No dnxcore50, only .NET 4.52.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a known issue with the OmniSharp-roslyn server which powers VS Code, see: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/265

I suspect you might have better luck using the [yeoman ASP.NET 5 generator](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet) to generate an ASP.NET 5 Console application.

See: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/yeoman.html
And http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/console.html

Comment: A fix for this issue has now landed in omnisharp-roslyn [v1.4.1](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/releases/tag/v1.4.1) (and [omnisharp-atom](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-atom/) has also been updated).

No idea when that version will land in VS Code. The current version of [VS Code (0.8)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates#_languages-c35-on-omnisharp-111) was released with OmniSharp v1.1.1.